# Использование Sqlite3 из под Electron JS

Tags: node.js, sqlite3, electron, node-modules

Пишу нативное приложение на Electron и в нём хочу использовать БД. Создание таблицы и запись в неё осуществляется через вызов функции, посредством нажатия на кнопку.

Кнопка:

```
<button onclick="createSave()">Бла-бла-бла!</button>
```

Функция:

```
function createSave() {
try {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE user(class TEXT, hp INT, power INT)');
    db.run('INSERT INTO user(class, hp, power) VALUES(?, ?, ?)', [Class, hp, power]);
    db.close();
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

}

Когда жму на кнопку, выдаёт следующую ошибку:

[image: TypeError]

Такое ощущение, что во время вызова функции, приложение забывает про существование node.js.

В чём может заключаться моя ошибка или что мне может помочь в данной ситуации?
Первый раз работаю с электроном. Ещё не особо понимаю, как он работает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853950/4496422. но я бы всё делал в main-процессе через ipc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему. В основном скрипте в параметры окна добавил три строчки и всё заработало.

```
nodeIntegration: true,
nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
contextIsolation: false
```